# Node serving an old version but still compiles updates

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm creating a React application and am running into this issue. When I make changes to code, Node does recompile and even recognizes errors in the code, but no matter what, the localhost in the browser remains unchanged. Here's a list  of things that I've tried:

- Clearing the browser's cache and hard reloading the page
- Switching browsers
- Turning Node off and on again
- Reinstalling Node
- Creating a new directory, copying over the code, and then installing Node there
- Turning the whole computer off and on again

I'm not sure what to try anymore. When installing Node, there are no errors, and no errors if I run `npm start` or `npm build`. As I said, I know Node is looking in the right directory since it recognizes when I make changes and shows errors when the code fails to compile. I also know I'm looking at the right localhost page since it isn't available when Node isn't running. However, the page remains perfectly usable and unchanged even if the code fails to compile, and actually is able to load before Node compiles all of the code.

I got the code itself from a zip file from GitHub and people who have their frontend set up have no issues with it. Node and all the other dependencies were downloaded by me, again, with no errors.

I'm using Node v10.16.0 and npm v6.9.0

Comment: Are you executing the `npm start` from the correct folder?

Comment: I am executing it in the correct folder...

Comment: Try to generate some error, Probably you can remove some block of code from one your main file, and then save it and reload the server/page and see if you are getting the same result in your browser.

Comment: As stated in the question, if I do that, Node shows that there is an error in the code, but no changes happen in the browser.